# Do we excrete waste in same order of food intake?

Tags: digestion, gastroenterology

Obviously I do not expect we poop out molecule by molecule in exact order. All I am  asking is, is it possible for us to pass stool's of today's food before we poop yesterday's food. Does our GI tract act like a First-In-First-Out pipeline always?

Otherway to frame the questions is, If we consume hard to digest food 'A' first, easy to digest food 'B' next, is there a chance of B to come out before A?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! We encourage you to do some research on your own and then, informed by what you have learned, ask any questions you still have (ideally with references to reliable sources).  ——— Please take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. Thanks! 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the food you have eaten. Some foods are more difficult to digest than others, and will take longer to pass through your digestive tract. Once your waste has accumulated in your colon and formed a semi-solid/solid stool, then it's likely no material can make it past that, or combine with it, but until that point, it makes sense that material from items could intermingle and get jumbled up.

The following provides rough guidelines for how long it can take to digest food:
https://www.mayoclinic.org/digestive-system/expert-answers/faq-20058340